# Return method reference

Tags: java-8, method-reference

I am playing around in Java 8. How can I return a method reference?

I am able to return a lambda but not the method reference.

My attempts:

```
public Supplier<?> forEachChild(){
     return new ArrayList<?>::forEach;
}
```

OR

```
public Function<?> forEachChild(){
     return new ArrayList<?>::forEach;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a small mis-understanding of how [method-references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) work.

First of all, you cannot `new` a method-reference.

Then, let's reason through what you want to do. You want the method `forEachChild` to be able to return something that would accept a `List` and a `Consumer`. The `List` would be on which object to invoke `forEach` on, and the `Consumer` would be the action to perform on each element of the list. For that, you can use a [`BiConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html): this represents an operation taking 2 parameters and returning no results: the first parameter is a list and the second parameter is a consumer.

As such, the following will work:

```
public <T> BiConsumer<List<T>, Consumer<? super T>> forEachChild() {
    return List::forEach;
}
```

This type of method-reference is called "Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type". What happens is that the first parameter of type `List<T>` becomes the object on which `forEach` will be invoked, by giving it as parameter the `Consumer`.

Then you can use it like:

```
forEachChild().accept(Arrays.asList("1", "2"), System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some points.

You can't instantiate unbounded type instance.

```
List<?> list = new ArrayList<?>();
```

Second, as Tunaki mentioned, you can't make references to `new MyObject::staticMethod` **when you make method references**

The other thing is, `forEach(Consumer<T> consumer)` *(Terminal operation for pipeline streams)* doesn't return anything. It only eats whatever we feed it.

-Hope this may help :)

Comment: While `new ArrayList<?>()` isn’t allowed, `List<?> list = new ArrayList<>();` works smoothly, simply because it doesn’t matter whether you use `new ArrayList<?>()` or `new ArrayList<Object>()` in that context. Further, you *can* make references to an instance method (note that `forEach` is not `static`) of a new object, e.g. `Consumer<Consumer<Object>> c=new ArrayList<>()::forEach;` is a valid statement, though not much useful.

Comment: yeah. you are indeed correct. `new ArrayList<>();` is the old Java way. Before Java 1.5. *Before Generics were born*

Comment: **No**. `new ArrayList<>()` is the Java 7 and newer way. That wouldn’t compile in earlier version. Look closer.

Comment: Opps!. my bad. it has diamond operator. :)