# Method reference and Lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda

I´m currently reading through someone else´s code and he has the following two methods:

```
public static double fac(double d) {
    return d <= 0 ? 1 : d * fac(d - 1);
}

public static DoubleUnaryOperator getfun() {
    return LamdaTests::fac; // LamdaTests is the classname of this class
}
```

First of all, i´m currently trying to understand lambda expressions/method references.

I have 2 questions:

1) What does the getFun() method exactly do? It should call the fac(double d) method in this class LambdaTests right? But with which argument and how can the return value be a DoubleUnaryOperator, shouldn´t "LamdaTests:fac" return a double?

2) What would be the equivalent Lamda expression for Lamdatests::fac in this case?

Edit: As far as i know

```
return LamdaTests::fac;
```

should be equal to

```
return x -> fac(x);
```

But i just dont understand where it gets the argument x from.

Comment: Take a look at The Java Tutorial, [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) section and [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) section. If, after reading and trying the examples there, you still don't understand something, then come back and ask again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return method reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37499675/return-method-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getFun` doesn't call anything. It just returns a reference to the `fac` function. You need to call the returned function still to get a result. `getFac` isn't very useful here, so that may be what's confusing things. In reality, you would just use `LamdaTests::fac` directly, unless that method was private.

For the latter question, think of it this way:

```
x -> fac(x)
```

is a function that takes a double and returns a double. What is `fac`? It's the same thing: a function that takes a double and returns a double. The argument is just implicit here.